# CSV exported as comma separated and decimal separator is CSV

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have a problem, where i exported some large csv files, and after some time the separator jumped back to default comma, but the problem is that the decimal separator of the software (SQL Developer) is comma too, so im getting ghost columns now and columns are having the wrong values.

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, it changed back after a while? How did you export it in the first place? Other delimiter than comma?

Comment: i used semicolon, then now that i wanted to work with these files, i found out that after a while everyone of them has a comma as a separator. My last hope is that im creating a script to change every comma except every nth one, but maybe i can find some more handy solutions

Comment: I'm struggling to understand, even now. You can save/export data with another delimiter than a comma. You have to change your system list delimiter to do so, save/export data, and change back your delimiter. And what you are saying is that within the exported data you have noticed that all semicolon has reverted back to a comma?

Comment: the separator for the CSV, and the decimal separator is both commas. Since decimal separators are used in numbers, theres no string enclosure. 

i.e.: 
"col1", "col2", "col3"
"name",12,43,"hobbies"

as you can see, theres 3 columns, separated by commas. 
but 4 values, since the 12,43 has a comma as a decimal separator, so it makes up 4 columns in the minds of every program. I want a way to change this to dots, or every other commas to semicolons.

Comment: I get the problem these commas give, I just don't get how the delimiters got changed back to comma in the first place. You sure you have saved it with other delimiters after you have changed the system delimiter?

Comment: Excel - Parameters - Additional - Edition parameters - Use system delimiter - set Off  and specify the point (names are approximate - I have no eng. version). You may also try to use another output format (for example, tab-delimited .TXT).